# Can you draw text shadows/outlines using Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class that draws a rounded rectangle, puts a border around it, and a piece of text in the middle.

I would like to add a shadow/outline to the text, so that the text looks inset like the title on a UINavigationBar.

Is this possible with CoreGraphics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inset text is created by adding a white shadow without a blur below the text (assuming light coming from the top.)

In CoreGraphics, set the shadow before drawing text

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, 
                            CGSizeMake(0, -1), 
                            0,  
                            [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have white text, so I just changed the shadow color to black and this works well.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew you can set the shadow offset property of the button title label by calling `setTitleShadowOffset`: method on the button.

Edit:

I hope these links might help

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss
http://www.wideasleep.com/blog/?p=199

Comment: I would like to use core graphics drawing methods, using CGContext.